# How to Import Libraries into python project from GitHub

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a project in python using some libraries from GitHub that I found. I am using InstaPy and Instagram-API-python. 
 My project structure is as follows

- Project(main folder)
- Instapy(sub-folder)
- Instagram-API-python(sub-folder)
- insta.py

How would I import both these into the insta.py file? I am new to python and not sure how the imports work.

Comment: did `import instapy` not work? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Don't copy them into your project folder, use `pip` to install them on your Python path.

But first, read about [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Once you have your virtual environment set up and activated you can install the packages thus:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy.git
$ pip install git+https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python.git
```

Then, in your python script just import them

```
from instapy import InstaPy
import InstagramAPI
```

and use them.

I followed these instructions and it (mostly) worked. It looks like `InstagramAPI` needs an executable installed (`ffmpeg`) which I'm not wanting to install on my laptop. It reports the error during the initial `import`.

I could definitely import `instapy` .. but notice that it is all lower case.
But since there is only the InstaPy class in the instapy module, it's best to simply import it this way.

More on InstaPy here: https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy

Comment: I did it like that and I still get the ImportError: No module named instapy
 error

Comment: Check their README's. They both have installation and usage instructions

Comment: @JohnDoe The READMEs are unreliable. Updated the instructions

Comment: @JohnDoe Don't install the package with pip...

Just either download or clone the whole repository and follow the getting started instructions in the Readme from there...

Still working on getting this thing easy to install using pip